# How to avoid the following purify detected memory leak in C++?

Tags: memory-leaks, memory-management, purify

I am getting the following memory leak.Its being probably caused by std::string.
how can i avoid it?

```
PLK: 23 bytes potentially leaked at 0xeb68278

  * Suppressed in /vobs/ubtssw_brrm/test/testcases/.purify [line 3]

  * This memory was allocated from:

        malloc         [/vobs/ubtssw_brrm/test/test_build/linux-x86/rtlib.o]

        operator new(unsigned) [/vobs/MontaVista/Linux/montavista/pro/devkit/x86/586/target/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6]

        operator new(unsigned) [/vobs/ubtssw_brrm/test/test_build/linux-x86/rtlib.o]

        std::string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned, unsigned, std::allocator<char> const&) [/vobs/MontaVista/Linux/montavista/pro/devkit/

x86/586/target/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6]

        std::string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned) [/vobs/MontaVista/Linux/montavista/pro/devkit/x86/586/tar

get/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6]

        std::string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(std::string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::alloc

ator<char>> const&) [/vobs/MontaVista/Linux/montavista/pro/devkit/x86/586/target/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6]

        uec_UEDir::getEntryToUpdateAfterInsertion(rcapi_ImsiGsmMap const&, rcapi_ImsiGsmMap&, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<

char>> const, UEDirData >>&) [/vobs/ubtssw_brrm/uectrl/linux-x86/../src/uec_UEDir.cc:2278]

        uec_UEDir::addUpdate(rcapi_ImsiGsmMap const&, LocalUEDirInfo&, rcapi_ImsiGsmMap&, int, unsigned char) [/vobs/ubtssw_brrm/uectrl/linux-x86/../src/uec_UEDir.cc:282]

        ucx_UEDirHandler::addUpdateUEDir(rcapi_ImsiGsmMap, UEDirUpdateType, acap_PresenceEvent) [/vobs/ubtssw_brrm/ucx/linux-x86/../src/ucx_UEDirHandler.cc:374]
```

Comment: Are allocating string objects on the heap like : string *ps = new string(); ?  

Theres very little chance that the standard library is leaking. Purify often gives false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a case where Valgrind indicated I had leaks in `std::string`, but I couldn't see how. It turned out that I was leaking another object that held strings by value, but Valgrind correctly also caught the leaked string memory (which was the vast majority being leaked). I suspect that `uec_UEDir` isn't managing its strings correctly or is being leaked itself. I actually ended up finding my problem by very careful code inspection.